# Is there a way to type hint that a tuple can be searched in a binary way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

Can you tell Python that a list of strings is sorted and can be searched in a binary way?

Say you have a tuple of strings like so:

```py
from typing import Tuple
words: Tuple[str] = ("alphabet", "bike", "car", "house", "word")
```

Firstly, have I type hinted this correctly?
Secondly, is there a way to tell python that this tuple can be searched in a binary way (because it's sorted) or is it unnecessary?

Comment: `Tuple[str]` would be a 1-tuple of a string, per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Tuple) you want `Tuple[str, ...]`. Sortedness is a matter of value rather than type, I don't think that's supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type annotation should be `Tuple[t1, t2, ...]` where `t1, t2...` are the types fo the corresponding tuple values. The way  you have typed hinted your tuple, it implies that it's a tuple with a single string item in it.

The type hint system is created to bring static-like declarations to python, so two things to note

- annotating tuples would make sense if you have tuples of 2-3 items (eg, `Tuple[number, number]` to denote a 2D point). What you have is a collection, and would be better annotated as `Iterable[str]`.
- There's no way to denote that a collection is sorted, because *type* annotation annotate just *type*, which is independent of whether the collection is sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You can not say that a tuple is binary searchable using type hints. However, you can write a decorator to wrap your functions with that enforce all input tuples are sorted. This is probably a good idea if you have many functions that require sorted tuples as inputs. It does NOT modify the tuples (it can't -- tuples are not mutable)

```py
def is_sorted(t):
    """ Returns true if the tuple, t, is sorted """
    return sorted(list(t)) == list(t)

def enforce_sort(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        new_args = [None]*len(args) # Since args is a tuple, we can't modify it
        for n, arg in enumerate(args):
            new_args[n] = arg 
            if isinstance(arg, tuple):
                ## Do you want to sort it?
                new_args[n] = tuple(sorted(arg))
                ## Or do you wait to raise an exception if its not sorted?
                # if not is_sorted(arg):
                #     raise ValueError("Input tuple must be sorted")
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            if isinstance(v, tuple):
                ## Do you want to sort it?
                kwargs[k] = tuple(sorted(v))
                ## Or do you want to raise an exception if its not sorted?
                # if not is_sorted(v):
                #    raise ValueError("Input tuple must be sorted")
        return func(*new_args, **kwargs)
    return inner

@enforce_sort
def show_twoples(t1, t2):
    """ prints two tuples, t1 and t2 """
    print(f"t1: {t1}")
    print(f"t2: {t2}")

a = (1,2,3,4,5) # Sorted
b = (9,8,6,4,2) # Not sorted
c = [1,2,6,2,3] # Not sorted, but not a tuple so it won't be affected
print(f"\nOriginal: t1 = {a}, t2 = {b}")
show_twoples(a, b)
print(f"\nOriginal: t1 = {b}, t2 = {a}")
show_twoples(b, a)
print(f"\nOriginal: t1 = {a} t2 = {c}")
show_twoples(a, c)
print(f"\nOriginal: t1 = {c}, t2 = {b}")
show_twoples(t1 = c, t2 = b)
```

Output:

```
Original: t1 = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5), t2 = (9, 8, 6, 4, 2)
t1: (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
t2: (2, 4, 6, 8, 9)

Original: t1 = (9, 8, 6, 4, 2), t2 = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
t1: (2, 4, 6, 8, 9)
t2: (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

Original: t1 = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) t2 = [1, 2, 6, 2, 3]
t1: (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
t2: [1, 2, 6, 2, 3]

Original: t1 = [1, 2, 6, 2, 3], t2 = (9, 8, 6, 4, 2)
t1: [1, 2, 6, 2, 3]
t2: (2, 4, 6, 8, 9)
```

Depending on what you want, you can sort the tuples automatically in the decorator (which is what it is doing now), or you can raise an exception if the tuple is unsorted (by switching which part is commented out).